# How to add a C-wire to Weil McLain Boiler

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

I am having trouble installing a new wireless thermostat to my existing Weil McLain boiler.  My existing control wire utilized an Rh and W on the thermostat, but utilized the Y and G terminals on the boiler itself.  The installation manuals indicate I need to connect a new C-Wire from the C terminal from the boiler to their c terminal on the thermostat and reconnect the other wires as is, but that doesn’t work.  Do I need to relocate the wire on the Y terminal to the R terminal or am I missing something else?  [image]

Comment: Is the LWCO allowing the boiler to fire?  If the low-water cutoff has tripped, then the whole system will appear shut down because the thermostat terminals are downstream of the LWCO

Comment: Or, in other words, can you measure 24VAC between G and C?